# How to change XFCE to LXDE?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xfce, lxde

I've just installed LinuxMint **XFCE**, which seems to be still a bit to heavy for my hardware. Thus, I'm thinking about **LXDE** installation and wonder if a new Linux installation is necessary/advised in such case.

The question is: **How to switch easily?**

---

The additional questions are:

a) is it necessary to **remove the XFCE packages** or both DEs may be installed at the same time?

b) is there any way to simply switch between DEs (i.e. have **both DEs available** and boot with DE selected each time)?

c) are there any **performance consequences** of having more than one DE installed? it means: is clean LXDE installation faster than Linux with 2 separate desktops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You most certainly do not need a new installation. That would be like doing a new install in order to switch from firefox to chrome. The Desktop Environment is just another program running on the OS. There is no reason why you should not have many installed (I have cinnamon, MATE, xfce, gnome at the moment).

To install a new DE, just install the relevant package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Once the installation is finished, log out. You will be taken to the mdm screen (login screen) where you now can choose which DE to use for your session. The choice of DE is made at the time you log in, it has nothing to do with booting.

To answer your other questions, no you do not need to remove xfce, and no there are no performance consequences to having multiple DEs. The only time it may be a problem is if you have no space left on your hard drive, but that is the case for *any* program.

Comment: I tried this using Mint 18.3 with Cinnamon as the "native" DM. As well as the `lxde` package, I have (so far) had to install `lxde-common` and `lxsession-logout`. Without `lxde-common` I wasn't able to select the LXDE destop when logging in; without `lxsession-logout` the logout button didn't work.

Comment: Also, there are comments on a Mint community tutorial on this topic (https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1079) warning that switching between DMs can cause problems. I have no idea if those problems have been resolved more recently.

Answer (score 4):

And you can always set the `default` desktop manager that will load straight away on boot. Edit the file `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` and put the binary of your desktop manager of choice. In the file, I have

> /usr/sbin/mdm

which loads mdm by default.

Answer (score 0):

How to switch easily? Use a live trial multi DM specific distro that lets you decide which DM you prefer. No install necessary.

a) Multi DEs may be installed at the same time.

b) With many DE's your default boot preference is settable/switchable and depends on the base distro.

c) Upgrades may be faster and also it would be faster to find your apps on the menu without duplicates that are DM centric.